# UNIX SHELL Script Replace text with Sed,i have the program working,but for a simple particular case it is not working,how can i correct it?

Tags: shell, unix, sed

Problem statement is

If todays date is single digit,then replace that date with single * 
if the today date is double digit,then replace it with double *

my code works for single digit date.

but my sed code is unable to substitute double digit with double `**`.

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/sh
set `date`
if [ $3 -le 9 ]
then
       n=`cal | tail -n +3 | grep -n "$3"| cut -d ":" -f1 | head -n 1`
       n=`expr $n + 2`
       cal | sed "$n s/$3/*/"
else
       cal | sed "s/$3/**/"
fi
```

whats the error in this line

```
cal | sed "s/$3/**/"
```

assume `$3` contains value `19`.

here's the output of cal | cat -vte

```
abhijith@abhijith-compaq-420:~/Desktop$ cal | cat -vte
   December 2013      $
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  $
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  $
 8  9 10 _^H1_^H1 12 13 14  $
15 16 17 18 19 20 21  $
22 23 24 25 26 27 28  $
29 30 31              $
                      $
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cal | sed "s/$3/**/"` works fine for me. But I recommend to rewrite your script this way:

```
#!/bin/sh
day=`date +%d`
case $day in
?) cal | sed "s/ $day/ */" ;;
??) cal | sed "s/$day/**/" ;;
esac
```

**UPDATE**

Since you say it's not working for you, let's get back to the basics. What will be the output of this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
day=9; cal | sed "s/ $day/ */"
day=19; cal | sed "s/$day/**/"
```

I get:

```
   December 2013
 S  M Tu  W Th  F  S
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7
 8  * 10 11 12 13 14
15 16 17 18 19 20 21
22 23 24 25 26 27 28
29 30 31
   December 2013
 S  M Tu  W Th  F  S
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7
 8  9 10 11 12 13 14
15 16 17 18 ** 20 21
22 23 24 25 26 27 28
29 30 31
```

Comment: it just displays the calendar with no replacement for either 1 or 2 digit date.

Comment: But this works  
cal | sed "s/19/**/"

but i want a variable in place of 19,how can i do that?

Comment: Yes,if i replace * with X ,for single digit it replaces it with X but if its two digit,it doesnt!

Comment: i am Ubuntu 12.04 Operating system

Comment: This is indeed creepy,if i read the variable through "read date" it works,but not with set with date!!

Comment: i did,your code works,but if i read the value,rather than taking it from date!  i dont know whats wrong!...my code also works even yours works,but only when i read date,rather than from date command...

Comment: May be something wrong with my Ubuntu System,it worked at my Unix terminal at workplace and in your systems...

Comment: I imagine something is wrong in your reading code, and your variable that you think contains 19 actually contains something else, possibly excess whitespace